# how to end macro expansion in *scratch* buffer and return to writable buffer

Tags: keyboard-macros

In *scratch* buffer, Emacs can expand macros(C-c e; macrostep-expand).
But once I expanded the macro, it seems to become a read-only buffer.
I don't know how to end macro expansion and return to writable buffer.

It would be very helpful if you could tell me the solution.

My environment is below.

- GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0)
- WSL2

Thanks

EDIT
macro-expansion is a function of macrostep.el.

Comment: `C-c e` is reserved for end users, so whatever it is bound to, it should be *you* who defined that keybinding (hence we don't know what that might be).  If something else has bound `C-c e` (or any `C-c LETTER`) then please report it as a bug, as that's in breach of the documented conventions.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. In my setting, `C-c e` is bound to macrostep-expand.

Comment: What is `macrostep-expand`, and where is it defined? I don't see it in Emacs 27.1 from `emacs -Q`. Please provide all relevant info in your question.

Comment: Is this about keyboard macros or Elisp macros? The question is unclear. I suspect it might be the former, in which case the tags are wrong. Unless you clarify the question it should be closed, I think.

Comment: `macro-expand` is a function of [`macrostep.el`](https://github.com/joddie/macrostep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just to press q on the expanded macro.

according to M-x describe-bindings

```
q       macrostep-collapse-all
c       macrostep-collapse
u       macrostep-collapse
DEL     macrostep-collapse
n       macrostep-next-macro
p       macrostep-prev-macro
e       macrostep-expand
```

Comment: You didn't answer the questions in my comment, so the question (and answer) remain unclear. Based on the answer I'm guessing this is about keyboard macros, *not* Elisp macros, but you should provide a reference (link) for `macrostep-*`.